# Replace string if specific characters found in php

Tags: php

I want to replace the characters if specific characters found.
for example my text having below value :

```
$text = "@abc hi there!! @jkl,@xyz how are you?";
```

Here I want to replace all words which starts with '@' and output should be like

```
$text = "<a href='abc'>@abc</a> hi there!! <a href='jkl>@jkl</a>,<a href='xyz'>@xyz</a> how are you?";
```

words may seperate with blank space or comma (with/without space). I want to replace `"@abc"` with `"<a href='abc'>@abc</a>"`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I want to replace "@abc" with "@abc".??

Comment: Use regular expressions with [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg-replace)

Comment: I was trying using explode function twice. one for comma and another for blank space. but it does not seem good option. because i will have to implode the words to convert it to string again.

Comment: @fab - can u please give me code as I am not good in regex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$text = preg_replace('/@(\w+)/',"<a href='$1'>@$1</a>",$text);
```

Comment: Your code was incorrect, but you fixed it (before the grace period ended, too). Edit your answer so that I may change my vote.

Comment: Lol you serious? Mine had a slightly too large capture, while yours had syntax errors. So I edited yours, and you downvoted mine. Hilarious.

Comment: I voted down before you edited mine (or yours). My vote is locked in its current state unless you edit your answer, I can't change it even if I want to. Edit your answer, ping me in comments, and I will change my vote. It's not such a big deal...

Comment: I know it is not a big deal. I'm past the point where two rep points are meaningful to me. Just find your downvote funny, considering quality of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions:

```
$str = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", "<a href='$1'>@$1</a>", $text);
```

Note that the `\w+` is found in brackets, which causes it to be captured. Also note that it would fail with characters from different languages (Won't work on @שלום).